# Error al compilar: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"

Tags: android, gradle, manifest

Tengo este problema al compilar mi aplicación **DEBUG** en 4.4, en 8.1 funciona perfectamente.

He leido muchas preguntas sobre este error pero no me soluciona el problema, no sé que hacer, mi versión de Android Studio es 3.5, así que no tiene Instant Run

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.app-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.app-2,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Este es mi gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 35
        versionName "4.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //google
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    //otras
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.4.7'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".utilidades.MyApplication"
```

MyApplication

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        MultiDex.install(this);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementa el método `attachBaseContext()` y ahí inicializa el [modo multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override 
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    } 

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

       // MultiDex.install(this);   
    }

}
```

Comment: No me lo creo! Después de pruebas y pruebas eso era la solución! Muchas gracias, se ha solucionado!! Una duda, debería ponerle un if para que solo utilice MultiDex.install(this) en versiones inferiores a Android 5.0 o ya lo controla sólo multidex?

Comment: Me da gusto volver a saludarte y haberte ayudado. En realidad el soporte es para todas las versiones de sistema operativo si estas configurando app para multidex